# Enable and disable system overlays with shell command

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, shell, command-line, overlay

I'm trying to create an automatic Dark Mode using Tasker, which would work disabling overlays (to get a default light theme) and enabling others (to get a dark mode). For the light theme I run `cmd overlay disable --user 0 + package name`

However, when i try to use `com.android.system.overlay.dark` (an overlay that comes with my custom ROM) it changes it for a moment and gets back to how it was before.

If I do `cmd overlay list | grep dark`, I can see for a moment that it does get disabled, and enables itself again. When i run `cmd overlay enable` it does the same, enables and then disables the overlay.
I also tried running the command with `su`

If I change the theme from the ROM settings, everything works fine. Also, the command works with other overlays from substratum themes and some settings overlays that come with the rom.

Im using HavocOS 2.9, with android 9.0

Can anyone help?